# Get two columns from @Query annotation having nativeQuery true JPARepository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a entity user

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User{

@Id
@Column(name="id")
private int id;
@Column(name="reward")
private double reward;

@Column(name="reward_id")
private double rewardId;

//Getter & Setters
}
```

Now what i need is to get reward and rewardId from @Query annotation from other table in DB at once.

I have tried using

```
@Query(value="SELECT reward,reward_id from Table_name")
 public List getRewards();
```

but when run it says no property associated with bean. And when i Select only single column it give in my query it runs perfectly

Please help as i am new to JPA and Hibernate
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Note that you may want to create a `Reward` entity class, and have a `Reward` object in `User` instead of `reward` and `rewardId` .

Comment: There are join in the to get reward  and rewardId so how we can make this as entity

Answer (score 2):

Just use [Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections):

```
public interface RewardProjection {
    Double getReward();
    Double getRewardId();
}

@Query(value = "select t.reward as reward, t.reward_id as rewardId from table_name t", nativeQuery = true)
public List<RewardProjection> getRewards();
```

Comment: @ashish did you open the link I provided? I think I can not explain it better than Spring Data authors! ))